# Accessing Google Apps Script with CURL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

Im trying to access a Google Apps script via CURL. The problem is that the current session is not sent along when requesting the script and requires me to log in again. How can I maintain the current session vars when making the CURL request?

Answer (score 1):

cURL doesn't send along your browser's session information, as it's a different program. It's not possible to programmatically authenticate with an Apps Script web app.